# MSBuild XMLUpdate Question

Tags: msbuild

I am using the XMLUpdate to update an xml formatted file in MSBuild. It updates fine but adds `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top after update. Here is my statement that updates

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

<XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(AppName).alx" Xpath="/loader/application/version"  Value="$(AppVersion)" />
```

Is it possible to update without the xml element at the top?

Thanks
Ponnu

Answer (score 2):

The `<?xml ...>`  is more of a descriptor than a real XML element. It describes your document and, for example defines the encoding. It won't interfere with your existing elements. I think it is even a standard feature of a XML document (but I don't have the specs handy)